# How copy content of a tooltip with Vaadin?

Tags: tooltip, vaadin

With Vaadin framework, I display a tooltip with this method like belows :

```
myTable.setItemDescriptionGenerator(new ItemDescriptionGenerator() {

   @Override
   public String generateDescription(final Component source, final Object itemId, final Object propertyId) {
..
      if ("myPropertyOne".equals(propertyId)) {
              return "my description that I want to copy....";

       }

}
```

Is it possible to copy the description displayed on the tooltip ?

Thanks by advance.

Comment: Do you mean copy it in the webbrowser? It's not possible, unless you go into the dev mode of the browsers and navigate to the correct dom element. But toolstips are definitively not meant to have text to copy+paste

Comment: Could you please be more specfic, what your use case is? Copy to what?